# PHP mail function ignoring additional headers

Tags: php, email, contact-form, email-headers

I'm trying to send a mail using the php mail() function
but for some reason I don't get, additional headers are ignored.

This is my code:

```
$errors = '';
    $myemail = 'my@email.com';
    $myemail_bcc = 'my_bbc@email.com';
    if(empty($_POST['nome'])  ||   empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $errors .= "Error: You must fill Name and Email fields";
    }

    $name = $_POST['nome'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $message = $_POST['messaggio'];

    if (!preg_match(
    "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
    $email_address))
    {
        $errors .= "<br />Error: You must use a valid email address";
    }

    // spediamo la mail
    if( empty($errors))
    {
        $to = $myemail;
        $email_subject = "New Request from: $name";

        $email_body = "User data:.\n\n";
        $email_body .= "Nome: $name \nEmail: $email_address \nTelefono: $telefono \n";
        $email_body .= "Messaggio: \n$message";

        $headers = "From: John Smith <$myemail>\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: $name <$email_address>\r\n";
            $headers .= "Bcc: $myemail_bcc";

        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); 

        }
```

I've tried to vary the way I declare headers without names, just with emails:

```
            $headers = "From: $myemail \r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To:  $email_address\r\n";
            $headers .= "Bcc: $myemail_bcc";
```

and even just on one line

```
$headers = "From:  $myemail\r\nReply-To: $name <$email_address>\r\nBcc: $myemail_bcc";
```

But in no case the mail is sento to the Bcc address, and the "reply" function in client email does not use the Reply-to address.

where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the `PHP_EOL` constant instead of `\r\n`? On another note, definitely look at [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: I ran into a similar situation once and was told to declare $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1' ."\r\n";

Comment: For future readers, you absolutely don't want to use `PHP_EOL`.